# imlementation of binomial coefficient in Google JAX

Tags: jax

trying to implement custom MLE for binomial distribution (for learning purpose) stuck with implantation of binomial coefficient in google JAX . there is no analog for scipy.special.binom() implemented.
what shall i use instead ?

Comment: Does the binomial coefficient need to be implemented in JAX? I assume the training parameters are the p and q probabilities. If the (n, x) is static, then you can simply multiply by the scipy implementation (or use `scipy.special.comb` with argument `exact=True` if there are lots of trials).

Answer (score 2):

The binomial coefficient for general real-valued inputs can be computed in terms of the gamma function, which is available in JAX via [`jax.scipy.special.gammaln`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.scipy.special.gammaln.html). Here's one way you could define it:

```py
def binom(x, y):
  return jnp.exp(gammaln(x + 1) - gammaln(y + 1) - gammaln(x - y + 1))
```

Comment: How does a strict integer version work? Application of the recursion algorithm (with caching) or something like n//1*(n-1)//2*(n-2)//3 ...

Comment: I don't know of any way to do performant strict integer gamma functions in jax/XLA.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (sequential) integer implementation using JAX.

```py
def binom_int_seq(x : int, y : int):
    
    def scan_body(carry, values):
    
        n, d = values
        carry = (carry*n)//d
        
        return carry, None
    
    y = max(y, x-y)
    
    nd = jnp.concatenate(
        (jnp.arange(y+2, x+1, dtype = 'u8')[:,None],
         jnp.arange(2, x-y+1, dtype = 'u8')[:,None],),
        axis = 1
    )
    
    bc, *_ = jax.lax.scan(scan_body, jnp.array(y+1, dtype = 'u8'), nd)
    
    return bc

binom_int_seq_jit = jax.jit(binom_int_seq, static_argnums = (0, 1))
```

which gives

```py
x, y = 60, 31

bc_ref = sp.special.comb(x, y, exact=True)
# 114449595062769120

binom_int_seq(x, y)-bc_ref
# DeviceArray(0, dtype=uint64)

# Using above logarithmic gamma function based implementation
binom(x, y)-bc_ref
# DeviceArray(496., dtype=float64, weak_type=True)
```

Keep in mind the `binom_int_seq` implementation is only correct if

```py
(x-max(x-y, y))*sp.special.comb(x, y, exact=True) < jnp.iinfo(jnp.uint64).max
```

Unlike the real-valued version, the error will be sudden and catastrophic if this condition is not satisfied.

There may be other ways to increase this constraint, such as running cancellations based upon prime factorisation, without resorting to larger unsigned integers (/arbitrary precision).

A monoidal version could be implemented which computes the binomial coefficient numerator and denominator reductions then integer divides, but this places stricter constraints on the maximum arguments.